# Torch, why is my neural network producing only one output instead of many?

Tags: lua, neural-network, deep-learning, torch

I implemented a siamese neural network in Torch, but I have a problem on the dimensionality of the output.

In a simple script, that I developed just for testing, **it reads N elements in input and correctly generates N elements in output.**

But in my main software, the almost identical **model reads N elements in input and wrongly generates 1 element in output.**
The only difference between the two models are the number of neurons, that should not influence the output dimensionality

**Why is this happening?**

In this image you can see a comparison between the structures of the two Torch siamese neural networks.

[image: Comparison of the structure of the two Torch models]

**What might the mistake be?**
How to detect it?
Any ideas?

Comment: First, try toggling the existence of the dropout argument.  The default is 0.5, so it shouldn't affect anything, but let's remove that factor first.

That would leave only the 82<->6 argument; what is this?  If it's batch size, I see no problem; if it's something else, perhaps there's a mismatch with the actual input shape?

Comment: @Prune Thanks for helping. I removed the Dropout component and nothing changed. 82 and 6 are not the minibatch sizes, but the sizes of the neural networks.

Comment: Okay, that's a good sign in both cases, except that it doesn't give us a trivial solution.  Next, let's try the *real* paranoid shot: change the 82 to 6 and run again.  That *should* make the two models identical.  If you still get only 1 element, then there's something wrong beyond what you've displayed in this posting -- which should be a *huge* clue for you.

Comment: If the change to 6 works, then I'd try slowly raising it: 7 or 8, then trying to zero in on where the performance break occurs.

Comment: Thanks @Prune. I modified the right one to make it reading datasets having 82 dimensions, but unfortunately nothing changed. I also updated the question with a new image, in which there are 82 neurons in both the neural networks.

Comment: ... and you've dropped the explicit 0.5 dropout value?  The only difference I now see between them is that the one on the right reports the value.

Comment: Thanks @Prune. Dropout module is automatically set to 0.5 by default, if the user does not specify any value. So both architectures have dropout values set to 0.5, even if for some weird reason only the right model explicitly states the value. Any other ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113066/discussion-between-prune-and-davidechicco-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we got it in the chat thread.

I assume that you're running **Torch7** on CentOS.  Torch7 requires CentOS 7.0 or later.  It *installs* on CentOS 6, but doesn't work correctly; I think it's the back-propagation that has a subtle failure.